# Getting ready for Nullable Reference Types

Tags: c#, null, reference

Looking forward for C# [Nullable Reference Types](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/wiki/Nullable-Reference-Types-Preview) in C# 8.0. I do not like to use the preview implementation in a production code though, so just went with these simple helper classes intending them to be upgraded to new syntax by search and replace when time comes.

Usage sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var johnk = new FullName("John", "F.", "Kennedy");
    var johnd = new FullName("John", null, "Do");
    var johnn = new FullName("John", null, null); // throws
}
```

Where business class is:

```
class FullName
{     
    public FullName(Some<string> first, Option<string> middle, Some<string> last) =>
        (First, Middle, Last) = (first, middle, last);

    public string First { get; }
    public string Middle { get; }
    public string Last { get; }
}
```

Library code:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
struct Some<T> where T : class
{
    public static implicit operator Some<T>(T value) => 
        new Some<T>(value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException());

    public static implicit operator T(Some<T> some) => 
        some.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();

    Some(T value) => Value = value; 
    T Value { get; }
}
```

And

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
struct Option<T> where T : class
{
    public static implicit operator Option<T>(T value) => 
        new Option<T>(value);

    public static implicit operator T(Option<T> some) => 
        some.Value;

    Option(T value) => Value = value;
    T Value { get; }
}
```

Nothing fancy, just does the job and it would be easy to upgrade syntax…

Comment: I would decorate both the constructor and `Value` property with an explicit `private` access modifier.

Comment: It feels like I learn something new about C# syntax every time I read your questions. :) I had no idea you can use tuples to inline constructor implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some disadvantanges about this solution. You not only loose the argument-name inside the exception but if you are using ReSharper then you won't be able to quick-fix this in future.

Thus I think it's not necessary to create such helpers because as soon as the new feature is there, ReSharper will probably have nice quick-fix for that so it'll turn all `if(foo == null) throw new ArgumentException(..)` into the new syntax. I doubt ReSharper will be able to quick-fix this.

Besides if you properly [decorate](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Code_Annotations.html) your code with the `[NotNull]` and `[CanBeNull]` attributes, you are half-way safe. Since I started using them, It's been ages that I last saw a `NullReferenceExcepiton` or `ArgumentNullExcepiton`.

---

I also find ReSharper's naming convention more appealing. This means

- `Some` becomes `NotNull` and
- `Option` becomes `CanBeNull`